# how to send a file like word via RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, esb, messagebroker, mime-message

I need to be able to send files like pdf or word via RabbitMQ (I think answer might be more generic meaning not specific to RabbitMQ but any broker I am however using RabbitMQ).

Is there are way to send them as mimes or do I need to convert to base64 and then send that.

Or am I going on a tangent here :( please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RabbitMQ doesn't look into the body of the message, you can send anything, any binary data.

Comment: Accepting you answer it . Simple and clear pity :( that had to use other libraries for binary compression - thanks.

Comment: Hi @Shahzeb. how did you do the binary compression/extraction?

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 that was 7 years ago :) I am sorry not certain but might have been some of the google libraries.